# org.json.JSONObject is changing number into exponential form

Tags: json, rest-assured

I am using `json` object having `json` data as :

```
{
"name": "Black Cat",
"description": "Cat Family",
"PublicDirect1": **18446744073709551615**
}
```

While parsing it through :

```
JSONObject jsonobject = new JSONObject(jsonFile);
Using org.json.JSONObject
```

I am getting output `JSONObject` as :

```
{
"name": "Black Cat",
"description": "Cat Family",
"PublicDirect1": **1.8446744073709552E19**
}
```

I do not want **PublicDirect1** value to be changed, I want to use the raw value 18446744073709551615 as it is, so how to do that?
Any other class which I can use?

Comment: I don't see any change in the response(`PublicDirect1` value). May I know the version of json jar you are using? I tried with below version it was giving correct response as you like to see. maven repository source for json version: `https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.json/json/20140107`

Answer (score 0):

Please check the data type of `PublicDirect1`. In case it is not String, Convert that to `String` and then get that value. By this you can preserve the value.

Comment: it is an unsigned long value. I need to test this specific datatype only. Hence, cannot change the datatype while Posting the JSON?

Comment: The value might be crossing the limit that's why it is being converted to exponential. In this case either the developer has to change the model to accommodate the required value or the value is wrong. You might file a bug.

Comment: The value and datatype both are right, as they are working with API from Postman.
But they are failing in automation script as the value is getting changed by JSONObject jsonobject = new JSONObject(content);

I am using import org.json.JSONObject;
Should I try changing this?

Comment: How about de-serializing the object to a POJO and then extract its value. That way you can force the data type to be String.